# Read value of selected option in Component

Tags: typescript, angular-material, html-select, angular7

By using Angular7 CLI, I am trying to read the value of `mat-select` which has a `FormControl` attached to a `FormGroup`. On reading the value - it shows value at `[object object]`

As per one the solution, I have added `[(value)]="selectedOption"`. But this is not as per official documents

Component code

```
purposeControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
purposeList: Purpose[] = [
    {id: '0', value: 'Self Care'},
    {id: '1', value: 'Caring for someone'},
];

validateVitalsFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  purposeControl: this.purposeControl,});
```

---

### Implemented a 'submit' button to submit data

Back to component :

```
onFormSubmit(): void {
  console.log('Purpose:' + 
this.validateVitalsFormGroup.get('purposeControl').value);
}
```

HTML code is

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selectedOption" placeholder="Purpose" [formControl]="purposeControl" required >
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let purpose of purposeList" [value]="purpose">{{purpose.value}} </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="purposeControl.hasError('required')"> Please choose a Purpose</mat-error>
    <mat-hint>{{purposeControl.value?.value}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

The expect the value-id selected in the HTML,i.r 0 OR 1.

Comment: I some edit you code

Comment: when you add some code, please edit your post instead of posting a comment. This time, I've edited your post to include the code that you shared, please do so yourself next time

Comment: Now, from your post it's totally unclear what your question is, please edit it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

For valueto select you must define purpose.id instead of simple `purpose`, because `purpose` is object.

```
  <mat-option *ngFor="let purpose of purposeList" [value]="purpose.id"> //HERE USE purpose.id if you wanna to use Id as a value;
    {{purpose.value}} 
  </mat-option>
```

Than you can use :

```
onFormSubmit(): void {
  console.log('Purpose:' + 
  this.validateVitalsFormGroup.get('purposeControl').value);
}
```

Or if you wanna to use purpose object as whole value you must :

```
 onFormSubmit(): void {
  console.log('Purpose:' + 
  this.validateVitalsFormGroup.get('purposeControl').value.id);
  this.validateVitalsFormGroup.get('purposeControl').value.value);
}
```

Comment: This line - this.validateVitalsFormGroup.get('purposeControl').value); printed Id. So I am good with it.

Comment: You are welcome! Be free to ask me any questions.Your like to anwer is  best motivatin to me to help people.So...)